# Does the steady state distribution of a Markov chain change, when minimizing it?

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Say I have this Markov chain. Then I perform bisimulation on it, where I find the largest relation between the states of the Markov chain. Finally I can construct a bisimulation quotient/minimization (I think this is similar to a DFA minimisation) where the markov chain has become significantly smaller. That's all good.

What I'm speculating about is whether the steady state distribution actually changes? If it does then how is it still related to the original steady state distribution of the un-minimised markov chain?

I can't seem to get my head around it. You have new states where each contains a group of states. But the probability would still be the same, you just have less states in the probability transition matrix. Right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, the topic of bisimulation may not be familiar to others, so I would encourage you to provide some references, especially when talking about bisimilar stochastic processes. I think, it shall be related to the probabilistic notion of [lumpability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumpability).

Now, bisimulation is a relation between two systems: two Markov Chains may be bisimilar if they have the same labelling/output structure, but different state spaces - in fact our main hope is that we can find a bimilar Markov Chain over a smaller state space. Say, we start with a Markov Chain $C$ with $n$ states and construct a bisimilar Markov Chain $\bar C$ with $m<n$ states. Their invariant distributions cannot be the same for a simple reason that an invariant distribution of $C$ satisfies $\pi\in \Delta_n$ whereas $\bar\pi \in \Delta_m$, where
$$
  \Delta_i:=\{p\in\Bbb R^n_+:p\cdot \mathbf 1 = 1\}
$$
is the $i$-dimensional probability simplex. Yet, it is an interesting question whether $\bar\pi$ can be obtained from $\pi$ in a simple way.

Ok, let $X$ be the state space of $C$ and $\bar X$ be the state space of $\bar C$, and let $p$ and $\bar p$ be the corresponding stochastic matrices. Let $f:X\to \bar X$ denote the abstraction map, that is for all $x\in X$ and $\bar y\in \bar X$ it holds that
$$
  \bar p(\bar y|f(x)) = \sum_{y\in f^{-1}(\bar y)}p(y|x).
$$
Let $\pi$ be any invariant distribution of $p$, that is for all $y\in X$
$$
  \sum_{x\in X} p(y|x)\pi(x) = \pi(y).
$$
Denote $\bar\pi := f_*\pi$ that is $\bar\pi(\bar y) := \sum_{y\in f^{-1}(\bar y)}\pi(y)$. We have
$$
\begin{align}
  \sum_{\bar X\in \bar X}\bar p(\bar y|\bar x)\bar\pi(\bar x) &= \sum_{\bar x\in \bar X}\sum_{x\in f^{-1}(\bar x)}\bar p(\bar y|\bar x)\pi(x) = \sum_{x\in X}\bar p(\bar y|f(x))\pi(x)
\\
&= \sum_{x\in X}\sum_{y\in f^{-1}(\bar y)}p(y|x)\pi(x) = \sum_{y\in f^{-1}(\bar y)}\sum_{x\in X}p(y|x)\pi(x)
\\
&= \sum_{y\in f^{-1}(\bar y)}\pi(y) = \bar\pi(\bar y).
\end{align}
$$

Comment: I'll remember to provide the necessary references in the future. Okay I think I get what you're saying. Just to build on your last line, so there is no obvious relationship between $\pi$ and $\overline{\pi}$ to be inferred from looking C being minimised to $\overline{C}$ ? If that makes sense.

Comment: @sudo: I'm pretty sure there is a relation, especially if we can construct a bisimiulation via an abstraction map $f:C \to \bar C$ - in that case I'm pretty sure $\bar\pi = f_*\pi$, however I am now trying to check the literature on that topic. Stationary distribution are used a lot in model-checking, so I'm pretty sure somebody did that.

Comment: If you could share your findings here I would be very grateful. I did try to have a look around but couldn't really find anything, which then led me to here.

Comment: Could it possibly be something to do with the graphical structure? I mean the whole point of quantitative properties are to find the probability of reaching a success set of states. So could looking at the BSCC(Bottom Strongly Connected Components) or SCC (Strongly Connected Components) tell us anything about the relationship?

Comment: @sudo Ok, I'm sure that what I wrote holds: if $\pi$ is stationary for if $C$ then its pushforward is stationary for bisimilar MC. That holds in great generality, but in discrete case it shall be very easy to prove, just need to reach laptop. It won't work vice-versa though: from stationary distribution over smaller abstract MC you can't directly get that over the bigger original one, but of course it gives you constraints which may be useful.

Comment: That's very interesting. I would very much like to see how to prove it, if you have the time.

Comment: @sudo: edited ${}$

Comment: Thank you. I need to spend some time understanding your proof though. My math knowledge is average at best! Just a question, the vertical bar that you use. I'm used to it having a meaning of OR, is that the case here as well? Or maybe division?

Comment: @sudo that's conditioning - just how I write transition probabilities. As you may know, to each MC there corresponds a stochastic matrix $P$. Its entry $P_{xy}$ is the probability of going to $y$ from $x$. I just write it as $P(y|x)$. I can go step over step in the proof if you need assistance.

Comment: @sudo: can I ask you why are you interested in that topic? I was working on related things, and know that probabilistic bisimulation community is quite tiny.

Comment: Sure. I'm an MSc student taking a course in software verification (model checking) and this material was recently covered in a lecture. It was also my impression that the community is very small, from searching around looking for answers for various questions I have :) Very interesting field though, but I'm a bit limited with a not so strong mathematical background. But I'm improving!

Comment: @sudo: cstheory.stackexchange.com may have more answers at least regarding non-probabilistic model-checking, I use it from time to time

Comment: @sudo, Thanks I'll try there next time.